# Python Matplotlib TypeError: Legend needs either Axes or Figure as parent

Tags: python, matplotlib

Will someone help me on how to resolve the error shown below? My issue is that I cannot plot the legend. I'm using Matplotlib version 3.3.4.

My code is

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df1[columns[0]].rolling(100).mean(), label='epsilon=0.25')
plt.plot(df1[columns[1]].rolling(100).mean(), label='epsilon=0.5')
plt.plot(df1[columns[2]].rolling(100).mean(), label='epsilon=1.0')
plt.axhline(y=200, color='r')
plt.ylim([-100, 300])
plt.legend()
```

My error is

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 32 plt.ylim([-100, 300])
> ---> 34 plt.legend()
>
> /opt/anaconda3/envs/quantenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py
> in legend(*args, **kwargs)    2736
> @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.legend)    2737 def
> legend(*args, **kwargs):
> -> 2738     return gca().legend(*args, **kwargs)    2739     2740
>
> /opt/anaconda3/envs/quantenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/*axes.py
> in legend(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 415         if len(extra_args):
> 416             raise TypeError('legend only accepts two non-keyword arguments')
> --> 417         self.legend* = mlegend.Legend(self, handles, labels, **kwargs)
> 418         self.legend_._remove_method = self.*remove_legend
> 419         return self.legend*
>
> /opt/anaconda3/envs/quantenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py
> in **init**(self, parent, handles, labels, loc, numpoints,
> markerscale, markerfirst, scatterpoints, scatteryoffsets, prop,
> fontsize, labelcolor, borderpad, labelspacing, handlelength,
> handleheight, handletextpad, borderaxespad, columnspacing, ncol, mode,
> fancybox, shadow, title, title_fontsize, framealpha, edgecolor,
> facecolor, bbox_to_anchor, bbox_transform, frameon, handler_map)
> 443             self.set_figure(parent)
> 444         else:
> --> 445             raise TypeError("Legend needs either Axes or Figure as parent")
> 446         self.parent = parent
> 447
>
> TypeError: Legend needs either Axes or Figure as parent

Edit:
As suggested by Lio, if I use `fig.legend()` I get the following figure.
[graph with legend outside the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxBoE.png)

which is close but the wanting the legend inside the graph.

Comment: Did you try adding plt.show() at the end of the code ?

Comment: It's same TypeError because the `.legend()` is the issue and before `.show()`.

Comment: Could you try this :
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
, and the replace all the plt by ax ?

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. Thanks for the suggestions.